# Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains compatible versions of the classes...?

Tags: java, spring

I'm working on a spring project that i leaved for a while, in fact i had to update some dependency and i think i wrong something.

Now, when i try to run the project i get this in the stacktrace:

`Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

```
org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.configureContext(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:378)
```

The following method did not exist:

```
'void org.apache.catalina.Context.addServletContainerInitializer(jakarta.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer, java.util.Set)'
```

The calling method's class, org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory, was loaded from the following location:

```
jar:file:/C:/Users/Fradm/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/3.0.0/spring-boot-3.0.0.jar!/org/springframework/boot/web/embedded/tomcat/TomcatServletWebServerFactory.class
```

The called method's class, org.apache.catalina.Context, is available from the following locations:

```
jar:file:/C:/Users/Fradm/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/9.0.73/tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar!/org/apache/catalina/Context.class
```

The called method's class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

```
org.apache.catalina.Context: file:/C:/Users/Fradm/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/9.0.73/tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar`
```

pom.xml:

`

4.0.0

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
3.0.0
 

art.idmax
idmaxart
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
idmaxart
Idmax.art back-end

<java.version>17</java.version>



org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-data-jpa


org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-web

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-crypto -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-crypto</artifactId>
        <version>5.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
        <version>0.11.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
        <version>0.11.1</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>0.11.1</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.73</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--        SWAGGER DOCUMENTATION  -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    </exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

`

Comment: I searched for a while, and all the similar questions are for different depenencies, so i decided to create a question too.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You’re depending on Tomcat 9, which doesn’t support the JakartaEE version of the servlet API.  Spring Boot 3 requires at least Tomcat 10.  In fact it provides such a dependency, so you shouldn’t need to specify one in your POM.

Comment: Now i'm getting this two errors: Caused by: java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest not present
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest

Comment: Sounds like you have some other dependency that requires the old javax servlet API.  Does the full stack trace give any clue as to what’s requiring that class?

Comment: There're a lot of lines all relative to spring-core, spring-plugin-core, spring-context and spring-boot

Comment: You basically need to sort out your dependencies to be consistent. For example, you’re using `spring-boot-starter-parent` 3.0.0 but I just noticed you also have `spring-boot-starter-security` 2.7.5.  Ideally you don’t want to be specifying explicit versions on anything you don’t have to (and especially not on Spring dependencies), because the parent POM will define consistent versions.